# Avoid O(n^2) when matching persons in databases - parallel person matching

Tags: database

I have millions of "people" records - say the customers for client one and customers for client two.  We want to match the people in client one and client two together - for example finding that "Mr Joel Spolsky" is in client one database and matching him to "J Spolsky" in client two, creating a totally new record in "master database".

THe exact algorthim to match two candidates is not important, what is important is that the most obvious solution is to take every record in client one and compare to every record in client two.
This quickly becomes an enormous task, especially with clients three four five etc.

Does anyone have any interesting approaches to improve performance?

Comment: Is there a perfect 1-1 association between the databases?

Comment: It does not feel like it :-)  Actually I mean n^y where n is records and y is clients.  I think, but my maths may be a bit hazy

Comment: Is it possible to pre-sort the lists of clients in both databases? And perform some kind of matching that takes advantage of the fact that looking up a client in a sorted list is Log(n) time? If so, you could get down to O(N * Log(N) ^ (Y - 1))

Comment: @vladislav - no there is an assumed rough overlap, but in theory there could be exact matches, no union, sub sets etc

Comment: What about cooking the lists in some other way? Extracting prefixes, titles? Essentially, doing something that reduces the amount of time it takes to locate a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious way is to create a common sort algorithm for all databases.  Sort your databases into lists, compare the "top" items in each sorted list, then keep discarding the "earliest" item until you find two items that match.  Record the match, discard the matches, and continue.

This works very well if you have, say, two sets of book ISBN numbers to compare to find duplicates between two libraries, but not so well with people's names where names may not be identical (J Smith vs John Smith, eg).  You can improve things somewhat by using a sort of KWIC scheme where you make several entries in your sorted list for each DB entry -- eg, one entry for name, one entry for address, one entry for social security number -- whatever criteria you might decide to match on.  A Soundex-type translation of the names may also be beneficial.

Comment: Accepting this answer on basis of above comment - I will try to return to this question with some data later

Answer (score 1):

The only way to avoid O(n^2) (or O(n^m) if there are more then 2 clients) is to sort the databases before searching.

But in order to be able to sort them you will have to come up with some normalized field which will always exactly match clients. (e.g. last word in the name field + postcode and all of that forced to lower case)

If you are able to sort the databases you can get your algorithm down to O(n log n)

Comment: They don't have to exactly match, only come within some reasonable distance of each other.  You could, eg, examine the heads of the match queues for some depth, until entries differed enough that it was obvious that no match could occur.  This would produce an O(N**2) algorithm, but N would only be this depth you search.

Comment: Now that is a really interesting idea.  Thank you - I would accept the answer but it's a comment -

Answer (score 0):

The matching algorithm *is important*. If you don't know anything about the matching algorithm you have to compare each against every other one in the other client database and you end up with O(N^2).

Comment: Untrue.  If you can somehow sort the entries you can reduce the order to essentially the n log n of the sort.

Comment: Nope, in that case you already know something about the matching algo: it compares some field and it does a prefix match. In that case you can sort on that field.

Comment: If you don't know *anything* about the matching algorithm, how can you even pose the question??

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying... The OP said the exact matching algorithm is not important. I said it *is* very important.

Comment: yi_H is correct. If the matching criteria is "The dot-product of the character arrays that make up each name equals 9583," I doubt that you can beat O(N^Y) performance.

Comment: He said it's not important (in his perception) to this query, not that he doesn't know what it is.

Comment: @Daniel: **I** Don't know the matching algorithm so **I** can't answer the question. Is that so hard to understand?? I don't know the exact grammar term for this.. "you" is a "generic" subject.

Answer (score 0):

it strongly depends on the database. Usually "intersect" is the fastest.

Now, you have a subtle difference between the two names in your database:  "Mr Joel Spolsky"  and "J Spolsky"

That's mean preprocessing the table. to be sure name matches, and maybe write your own "phonetic" index. that's seems out of topic, but if you have column "name" and "firstname" matching, but not column "prefix", what you do? (by mr and mrs alex jones).

Before you know it you end up with a rules engine, a decision making engine, and an interface for all "manual" cases (who are not auto-merge, or definite not the same), and 3 students merging (or flagging as "notsame") millions of addresses full time.

So before you get there, define what you want to merge *exactly*, then the algorithm can be chosen easily